# I want to view all recurring items from my outlook on to my c# application for today

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

I have a C# Windows Forms application that gets all of my appointments till date from Outlook and fills my appointments listbox but I only wanted all the appointments I have for today and I was successful in doing that by using the below code. But I am missing my recurring items in the list below, so I have an IT meeting every morning at 9AM to 10AM and its recurring why am I not able to see this in my appointments list box?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern recurrencePattern;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookApplication;

            try
            {
                OutlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                oNS = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");

                // Get the Calendar folder.
                Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oNS.CreateRecipient(username.Text);
                oCalendar = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

                oCalendar.Items.IncludeRecurrences = true;

                DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

                // Get the Items (Appointments) collection from the Calendar folder.
                oItems = oCalendar.Items;
                for (Int32 x = 1; x <= oItems.Count; x++)
                {
                    //Need to change how we are getting the appointment
                    //Apparently Outlook will return non-appointments in the calendar feed
                    try
                    {
                        oAppt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)oItems[x];
                        string now = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyy");
                        string jusdate = oAppt.Start.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                        if (jusdate == now)
                        {
                                Appointments.Items.Add(oAppt.Subject);
                                from.Items.Add(oAppt.Start);
                                to.Items.Add(oAppt.End);
                        }                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (oAppt.Body != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("      Calendar Body:" + oAppt.Body.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
}
```

What I tried so far:

```
private void CheckOccurrenceExample()       
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OutlookApplication;
             OutlookApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS;
    oNS = OutlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.AppointmentItem appt = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Items.Find("[Subject]='Recurring Appointment DaysOfWeekMask Example'") as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

    if (appt != null)
    {
                try
                {
                    Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = appt.GetRecurrencePattern();
                    Outlook.AppointmentItem singleAppt = pattern.GetOccurrence(DateTime.Parse( "11/13/2014 11:00 AM"))as Outlook.AppointmentItem;

                    if (singleAppt != null)
                    {
                        Appointments.Items.Add("11/13/2014 11:00 AM occurrence found.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
    }
}
```

I am hard coding in 11/13/2014 11:00 AM because I have a recurring appointments set up at that time for testing purposes, if the application works later on I will replace that with `DateTime.Today`

Comment: @juharr hi bud any idea on this issue? i want the method to iterate through all recurring appointments but only give me those for today.